# Minimal value of a product , Number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ two integers
Such that (a+b) is solution to the equation $x^2+ax+b=0$ .
Find the minimal value of the product $ab$.

• Please help  i'm really stuck on this , i cannot find any good bounds . This problem appeared in a morroccan national olympiad.

Comment: I dont know how to use lagranpe multipliers.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I hadn't noticed that you required $a,b$ to be integers. Given that, the goal is to try to solve the constraining equation in integers.

Comment: Maybe substitute $x$ for $a+b$ and get $(a+b)^2+a(a+b)+b=0$ and from then you get that $b$ divides $2a^2$ and also $a$ divides $b+b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$(a+b)^2+a(a+b)+b=0\\
2a^2+3ab+b^2+b=0\\
a=\frac{-3b\pm\sqrt{(b-4)^2-16}}4$$

Note that $b\ge 8$ or $b\le 0$. If $b\ge 8$ then the only possible values of $b$ are $8$ and $9$ (otherwise $(b-4)^2-16$ is not a square). If $b=8$ then $a=-6$, $ab=-48$. If $b=9$ then $a=\frac{-27\pm 3}4$, so $a=-6$, $ab=-54$

If $b\le 0$ then the only possible values of $b$ are $0,-1$. If $b=0,a=0$ and $ab=0$. If $b=-1, a=(3\pm 3)/4$, so $b=-1, a=0$, $ab=0$.

Thus the smallest value of $ab$ is $-54$.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Try $a=-6$ and $b=9$ in the initial equation. The smallest $ab$ is $-54$.

Comment: I have fixed the misprint: $3*9=27$, not $24$.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Mark Sapir's answer, but slightly simpler, write $(a+b)^2+a(a+b)+b=0$ as a quadratic in $b$ (instead of $a$), that is $b^2+(3a+1)b+2a^2=0$, and solve to

$$b={-(3a+1)\pm\sqrt{(3a+1)^2-8a^2}\over2}={-(3a+1)\pm\sqrt{a^2+6a+1}\over2}={-(3a+1)\pm\sqrt{(a+3)^2-8}\over2}$$

In order for $b$ to be an integer, we must have $(a+3)^2=9$, so $a=0$ or $-6$.  The case $a=0$ gives $ab=0$, while the case $a=-6$ gives $b=(17\pm1)/2$, i.e, $9$ or $8$. The smallest value is $ab=-6\cdot9=-54$.

Answer (score 0):

So ve have to solve $$2a^2+3ab+b^2+b=0$$ in integers. Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $x,y$ such that $a=dx$ and $b=dy$, then $x,y$ are relatively prime and we have $$d(2x^2+3xy+y^2)=-y$$ so $y=dz$ for some integer $z$ and now we have $$2x^2+3dxz+d^2z^2 =-z\implies z\mid 2x^2\implies z\mid 2$$ since $x,z$ are relatively prime. So we have 4 posible values for $z$, I will start only one, the rest are simillary.

- $z=2$ then $x^2+3dx+2d^2=-1$ so $(x+2d)(x+d)=-1$ so ...